# Doubt in jxl API?

Tags: java, jxl

While practicing the jxl API, i cant extract details from certain Excel sheet its throwing the following exception

Unable to recognize OLE stream
    at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.(CompoundFile.java:116)
    at jxl.read.biff.File.(File.java:127)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
    at Com.Parsing.ExcelFile.excel(Extract.java:13)
    at Com.Parsing.Extract.main(Extract.java:35)

Comment: What version of Excelfile are you trying to read?  I ask because Jexcelapi doesn't support Excel 2007 yet.

Comment: so to get an answer for this question on a q&a site the accepted answer is to go to a different q&a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's something wrong with the Excel file.

You might have better luck posting the question on [The JExcelApi Yahoo Group](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/JExcelApi) - the guy who created JExcelApi hangs out there and often answers questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven and filters, check that your .xls file is not filtered.